# Does PSR-12 say anything about the way how namespace imports and aliasing should be grouped and sorted?

Tags: php, php-7, psr-12

I'm working on a code quality automation with `phpmd`, `phpcs` and `phpcpd` tools. The code sniffer has been set to `--standard=PSR12`.

I was [unable to find](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) any details or recommendations in terms of the way how namespace imports and aliases should be defined:

- grouping with curly brackets or defining each one in a separate way (which at the moment is my biased suggestion)
- A-Z sorting

Eg:

```
use Foo\Bar\{ Lorem, Ipsum, Dolor };
```

vs:

```
use Foo\Bar\Dolor;
use Foo\Bar\Ipsum;
use Foo\Bar\Lorem;
```

If there's no standard recommendation I'm going to establish internal rule within my team, but if there is any, I'm happy to obey it.

Comment: If it's not mentioned in their code standard guide (which you've linked to), then they don't have an opinion about it.

Comment: You could make it a rule in your team that all PHP files should be reformatted using automated tools (e.g. PhpStorm), which should satisfy PSR-12. A linter could probably check that too - I wouldn't see any value in going above and beyond that.

Answer (score 4):

There is a couple of rules regarding the namespaces, but none who explicitly calls for the order. However, this is stated regarding the depth when declaring them:

> Compound namespaces with a depth of more than two MUST NOT be used. Therefore the following is the maximum compounding depth allowed:

```
use Vendor\Package\SomeNamespace\{
    SubnamespaceOne\ClassA,
    SubnamespaceOne\ClassB,
    SubnamespaceTwo\ClassY,
    ClassZ,
};
```

> And the following would not be allowed:

```
use Vendor\Package\SomeNamespace\{
    SubnamespaceOne\AnotherNamespace\ClassA,
    SubnamespaceOne\ClassB,
    ClassZ,
};
```

For a general rule, if it's not explicitly stated, then there is no standard. Either works.

You can read more about the existing rules here:

https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/